# Are variables supported in logrotate configuration files?

Tags: logrotate

I looked at logrotate.conf examples and everything in my /etc/logrotate.d directory. Nowhere was I able to find documentation on variables in these files.

I am trying to create a config file for rotating the logs of an application we are writing. I want to set the directory where logs are stored once, and then use it as a variable, like so:

```
my_app_log_dir=/where/it/is/deployed/logs

${my_app_log_dir}/*.log ${my_app_log_dir}/some_sub_dir/*.log {
    missingok
    # and so on
    # ...
}
```

Is that possible?

Answer (score 11):

You can achieve what you are looking for by implementing this kludge:

my-logrotate.conf ( NOTE: double quotes `"` are mandatory, also note that file names don't have to appear on the same line )

```
"*.log"
"some_sub_dir/*.log"
{
    missingok
    # and so on
    # ...
}
```

Then the actual logrotate script - my-logrotate.sh

```
#!/bin/sh

set -eu

cd "${my_app_log_dir}"
exec logrotate /path/to/my-logrotate.conf
```

Now you can add logrotate.sh to your crontab.

Answer (score 5):

You can use a bash "[here document](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/here-docs.html)" to create a suitable config file on the fly, either at installation time or before running logrotate.

A bash script might look like this:

```
cat >rt.conf <<.
"${my_app_log_dir}/*.log" {
    rotate 5
    size 15k
    missingok
}
.

logrotate  rt.conf
```

Answer (score 1):

Directly in the config file no (as far as my knowledge in logrotate goes).

Other solution:

- Use the include option to include parts of the configuration file from a directory. This can help you if you have a package for your application, the package can leave a file in that directory containing only the entries for your app.

Answer (score 1):

With logrotate 3.8.7,a test reveals that you can set and use variables in the pre-rotate and post-rotate script sections.

I tried this for a particular service log file.

```
   postrotate
         pid_file="/run/some_service/some_serviced.pid"
         test -e "${pid_file}" && kill -s HUP $(cat "${pid_file}") || true
         touch "${pid_file}.WAS_USED"
   endscript
```

After running logrotate in force mode to ensure the log file was rotated and the post-rotate script executed, on looking in /run/some_service, there was an additional file "some_serviced.pid.WAS_USED", thus proving that the use of the variable worked.

Answer (score 1):

Another option - probably not the cleanest - is to have a placeholder in the `logrotate.conf` file, which can be replaced on installation time for the real directory.

`logrotate.conf` :

```
(...)
XX_APP_LOG_DIR_XX/*.log {
(...)
}
```

Then you would have in your installation.sh something like:

```
sed -i "s/XX_APP_LOG_DIR_XX/$my_app_log_dir/" $CNF_DIR/logrotate.conf
```

If permissions are an issue, you can choose not to put the logrotate.conf in /etc/logrotate.d, but in any other directory. In such case you would have to call logrotate yourself, specifying your conf file:

```
logrotate $CNF_DIR/logrotate.conf
```